# How do you solve the second clues of part 1?

Tags: infamous-second-son, infamous-paper-trail

That second clues when you enter the code on the Track Drone.

Answer (score 2):

It's semi-random master mind type puzzle. You just need to enter random numbers and it will show you which ones you got right or wrong. X = Number not used at all, Yellow number = Correct Number but wrong position, Green = Correct Number and Correct Position. As far as I've seen it's always 6 digits long and the number should not repeat. So just start with six digits 0-9 (so 4 won't be used). Once you get the numbers correct (Yellow) just got to get their positions correct. Takes a bit of luck and a few rounds of starting over maybe (with a new random number) but you crack it eventually with process of elimination.

For more info check out IGN's Wiki, they just updated it with Paper Trail stuff. 
Infamous Paper Trail: Mission 2: Find the Suspect - Infamous: Second Son Wiki Guide - IGN
http://m.ign.com/wikis/infamous-second-son/Infamous_Paper_Trail:_Mission_2:_Find_the_Suspect?

Comment: Additionally it will lock you out after so many wrong attempts at it. Not sure what happens when it locks you out because I didn't let it happen. If you are not going to be able to get it with the last attempt simply go back to the home screen (your profile) and click on the link to drone again.